# Nodejs - print function name, line number and file name

Tags: node.js, logging, stack-trace

I'm researching various packages in Nodejs and cannot find that would suit my needs.
I would like to output the current line number, function name and src file to log, similar to how Bunyan logger does.

I looked into packages such as 'caller-id' but I cannot use it as it does not support 'strict' mode.

Other packages, such as 'capture-stack-trace' only return the file name without the line number & function name.

Is there a package that I'm missing and can suit my need?
Or is there an elegant way to generate this info in code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/tracer

Comment: I saw it, but it's a logging package. I use Bunyan as my logger, I just want to stop using it's 'src' option.

Answer (score 0):

**Determining the call source info is always turned off by default in every nodes logger. It is slow. Never use this option in production.**

We use [bunyan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan) for our micro services. This is copypaste from [documentation](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#src):

> The source file, line and function of the log call site can be added
>   to log records by using the src: true config option:
>
> ```
> var log = bunyan.createLogger({src: true, ...});
> ```
>
> This adds the call source info with the 'src' field, like this:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "src-example",
>   "hostname": "banana.local",
>   "pid": 123,
>   "component": "wuzzle",
>   "level": 4,
>   "msg": "This wuzzle is woosey.",
>   "time": "2012-02-06T04:19:35.605Z",
>   "src": {
>     "file": "/Users/trentm/tm/node-bunyan/examples/src.js",
>     "line": 20,
>     "func": "Wuzzle.woos"
>   },
>   "v": 0
> }
> ```

Comment: I already use Bunyan as the logger and the 'src' option. But I would like to turn it off and use my own 'src' object.